# Responsive Video

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I am trying to make my video a responsive one. The video has been positioned on top of an image (a tv screen) and it is important that it stays in the same place no matter how big the browser.

How would I go about making the video so it is

a) responsive
b) fixed in the position it is currently in.

The video has a height and a width so I am guessing it is harder to do.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Reece

```
<div class="videocontainer">
    <h1 class="videosheading"><strong>VIDEOS</strong></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 video-cell">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/TVWALLTWO.jpg"/>
                <video width="550" height="422" controls muted>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
                </video>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>

.video-cell {
    position: relative;
}
.video-cell img {
    width: 100%;
}
.video-cell video {
    position: absolute;
    top:6%;
    bottom:10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 7%;
    background-color: black;
    border: #2F2925 10px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making a video responsive is pretty much the same as making a picture responsive.
Mainly, you have 2 solutions:

1) Using width and max-width properties in %s instead of pixels.
The video will scale within his limits (and of course within the window limits).
This is a very common solution - but nevertheless, I do NOT suggest you use it.
This might not look good on screens that are in different aspect-ratio than your video.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_videos.asp

2) The better solution to your problem is using the media attribute for your source, adjusting different videos for different screen sizes (media queries).

```
<video>
<source src="video-widescreens" media="screen and (min-width:800px)">
<source src="video-widescreens" media="screen and (min-width:800px)">
<source src="video-smallscreens.mp4" media="screen and (max-width:799px)">
<source src="video-smallscreens" media="screen and (max-width:799px)">
</video>
```

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you. Does the second solution mean having a copy of the video in every different size?

Comment: @reecechapas You are very welcome. Basically yes, but it's not so much different size, but different aspects.

Comment: `media` is not a valid attribute, when the parent element of `source` is not `picture`. so this might have no fx. same goes for `srcset` and `sizes`. [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)